# Vuejs get edited inputs

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-component

**Logic**

1. I have checkboxes with inputs as label which values come from database so the text(value) is already exits. (done)
2. I want to make a list of checked items (done)
3. I want if I changed an item value get the changed value but it still gives me value of database (need help)

**For better understanding here is some screenshots:**

`1`

[image: one]

`2`

[image: two]

**PS:** If I change my input before checking the checkbox my value automatically jumps to default value (DB value)

**Code**

```
<template>
    <div class="input-group mb-3 active" v-for="(value, key, index) in list" :key="index">
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedFiles" :id="index" :value="value" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" >
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" :value="value" :id="index" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with checkbox">
    </div>

    <button class="btn btn-success btn-sm" v-show="isVisible" @click="generate">Generate List</button>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        name: "directories-component",
        data() {
            return {
                list: [],
                checkedFiles: [],
            }
        },
        methods: {
            getTheList() {
                //....
                this.list = res.data.data;
                //....
            },
            generate(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                console.log(this.checkedFiles);
            }
        },
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>
```

**Any suggestions?**

Answer (score 2):

Use `v-model` for the input text field

```
<div class="input-group mb-3 active" v-for="(val, index) in list" :key="index"> // removed key from iterator since list is an array
        <div class="input-group-prepend">
            <div class="input-group-text">
                <input type="checkbox" v-model="checkedFiles[index]" :id="index" aria-label="Checkbox for following text input" > // removed the :value attribute
            </div>
        </div>
        <input type="text" v-model="list[index]" :id="index" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with checkbox"> // Change added
    </div>
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the answer but there are 2 issues: `1)` `value` does not exist anymore (in first input `:value="value"`) `2)` for `v-model="val"` I'm getting `'v-model' directives cannot update the iteration variable 'val' itself.eslint-plugin-vue`

Comment: check the edited answer in `<input type="checkbox" ........`

Comment: Also I suggest you to maintain another object to track checkbox value like 
`checkedFiles: [false, false ...]`

Comment: thanks but still problem with `v-model="val"` remains

Comment: ok then try doing this `v-model="list[index]"`. Check the updated answer

Comment: Ok, that fix the issue with `val` but now I cannot get my values in console anymore (refer to my screenshots), it shows something like this `[empty × 3, true, __ob__: Observer]`

Comment: which one did you print on console, why is the `true` value inside that array?

Comment: let me take screenshot for you

Comment: here you go https://ibb.co/Cbhj2Ht

Comment: which one did you print on console, why is the `true` value inside that array?

Comment: `list` array is not supposed to have `booleans` but just `texts`

Comment: 1- None of my selected checkbox is printed in console (that's the issue).  2- you tell me :D

Comment: my best guess is true and false values are coming from checkboxes instead of coming from inputs

Comment: Ok, this does return the values `v-model="checkedFiles[val]"` but it's like this: `11_1raja: true` that `: true` part is extra

Comment: check the `v-model` statement, it should be `v-model="checkedFiles[index]"`

Comment: yes with that it returns true and false results, but with `checkedFiles[val]` it actually shows the strings but with extra `: true` not sure what the issue is :/

Comment: nope you shouldn't do that, becoz its converting array to object then

Comment: then what should I do? with `v-model="checkedFiles[index]"` it gets true and false and with `v-model="checkedFiles[val]"` it gets objects. so whats the solution here?

Comment: With `checkedFiles[index]` you can keep track of the items that are checked